# ASP.NET SessionState SQLServer mode - System.Xml.XmlBoundElement is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, serializable

I am currently modifying an ASP.NET (3.5) application to run in SQLServer SessionState
  mode. In the existing code, we have a serialized dataset that is currently stored in
  the Session using C#. I have a property that I use to extract this serialized dataset 
  and load it into a XmlDataDocument. My property is "something" like this:

```
public abstract class TransCommand 
{
 public static XmlDataDocument TransDoc
   {
     get
        {
          XmlDataDocument doc = null;
          if (Session["DataSetStore"] != null)
            {
              DataSet tds3 = new DataSet();
              MemoryStream tms3 = new MemoryStream(HttpContext.Current.Session["DataSetStore"] as byte[]);
              doc = new XmlDataDocument();
              doc.LoadXml(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tms3.ToArray()));
             }
             return doc;
         }
            set
            {
                Session["DataSetStore"] = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.OuterXml);
            }
        }
```

This works great except when I try to append an XmlNode to a node created from this
  TransDoc method.

```
public class AddChildren
  {
    XmlDataDocument doc = TransactionCommand.TransactionDoc;
    doc.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
    XmlNode dataNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//WebServiceResponse/Data");

    ......

    ArrayList lstNewInfants = new ArrayList();
    1stNewInfants.add(newInfants); //Adding new Infants XmlNodes into an arraylist.

    foreach (XmlNode nodInfant in lstNewInfants)
    {
      dataNode.AppendChild(nodInfant);
    }

doc.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = true;
TransactionCommand.TransactionDoc = doc; //Adds the modified doc back into the session
```

After appending this node, I receive the following exception after the Databind of the
  next page aspx page encountered:

```
Error Message:Type 'System.Xml.XmlBoundElement' in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.
Stack Trace:   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not a full answer, but I believe when you save something to the session, it is serialized internally by asp.net. Certain data types cannot be serialized implicitly, and it looks like you have found one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I see that an XmlBoundElement cannot be serialized but since I'm taking the OuterXml of the XmlDataDocument...which is a string and storing that string into the Session, I'm not sure why I would be getting this exception.